# cannot use a global variable inside my jquery template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

there is an artifact slider based on bootstrap on my page , i define a global variable(in java script) to count number of artifacts that returns from server to fill two different div with different classes . but when i'm using my variable in jquery template (my if case), i get error below

***TypeError: k.nodes is undefined***

and when i try to log my variable("artifactCounterV") in console.log(), after printing the value of variable i get this error

***TypeError: can't convert a to primitive type***

this is my homePage.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>home page</title>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var restUrl = "<c:url value = '/rest/core/goods/products/book' />";
    var restUrlOrderItem = "<c:url value = '/rest/order/orderItem/front/addToBasket/' />";
    var artifactCounterV = 1;
    $(function() {
        fillTable();
    });


    function artifactCounter()
    {
        return artifactCounterV++;
    }
    function fillTable() {
        $('#entityBody' + ' :not(script)').remove();
        $.getJSON(restUrl + "/front/list/getAll", function(entities) {
            if (entities.entityList)
                $('#GridRowTemplate').tmpl(entities.entityList).prependTo(
                        '#entityBody');
            else {
                $('#GridRowTemplate').tmpl(entities).prependTo("#entityBody");
            }
        });
    }

    function addToShoppingCart(productId) {
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : restUrlOrderItem + productId,
            success : function(res) {
                if (res)
                    return res.id
            }
        });

    }
    function goToBasketPage(){
        window.location="<c:url value ='/View/frontEnd/cart/Index.jsp'/>";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="confirm"></span>
    <%@ include file="Header.jsp"%>
    <%@ include file="TopMenu.jsp"%>
    <%@ include file="Commercial.jsp"%>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my artifactSlider.jsp

artifactSlider.jsp is icluded inside commercial.jsp and there is no java script code in commercial page,its pure html.

```
<!------------- product-slider ----------->
<div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide hidden-xs "
            data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div id="entityBody" class="entityBody">
                        <script id="GridRowTemplate" type="text/html">
                        ${console.log(artifactCounterV)}
                        {{if artifactCounterV == 1 }}
                            <div class="item active">
                            <div class="row">
                        {{/if}}

                        {{if artifactCounterV==6}}
                            <div class="item">
                            <div class="row">
                        {{/if}}
                                <div class="col-sm-2 item-holder">
                                    <div class="col-item">
                                        <div class="photo">
                                            <img
                                                src="<c:url value='/rest/attachment/front/getFile/' />${pictureCode}"
                                                class="img-responsive" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="info">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="price col-md-12">
                                                    <h5>${name}</h5>
                                                    <h5 class="price-text-color separator">
                                                        <span>price: </span> ${price} $
                                                    </h5>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="separator">
                                                <p class="btn btn-default col-md-12">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span href=""
                                                        class="hidden-sm" onclick="addToShoppingCart(${id})">add to basket</span>
                                                </p>
                                                <p class="btn btn-default col-md-12">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-list"></i> <a class="hidden-sm" href="">more</a> <span style="display: none">${artifactCounter()}</span>
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        {{if artifactCounterV==6 || (artifactCounterV>6 && artifactCounterV<=12) }}
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        {{/if}}
                    </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    <!------------- product-slider ----------->
```

Comment: is your JS code included before the DOM renders or after?

Comment: is this live somewhere we can debug?

Comment: dear @Cruiser i edited my codes like it realy is in my sample

Comment: @SergChernata unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

I remember trying something similar, the problem was i had to create the variables at window or document objects.